# RTL8822BE bluetooth not working on 20.04 / 5.4.0-37-generic but WiFi is good

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, 20.04

The combo wifi/bt card RTL8822BE on my Asus Z370-E seems stopped working since upgrading to 20.04. It worked fine in 19.10. The WiFi part works normally. Can anyone suggests how to solve this problem? Thank you.

```
rfkill list
```

> 0: phy0: Wireless LAN

> Soft blocked: no

> Hard blocked: no

`lshw`

> ```
>      *-pci:3
>          description: PCI bridge
>          product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #3
>          vendor: Intel Corporation
>          physical id: 1c.2
>          bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
>          version: f0
>          width: 32 bits
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
>          configuration: driver=pcieport
>          resources: irq:125 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:f7300000-f73fffff
>        *-network
>             description: Wireless interface
>             product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
>             vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
>             physical id: 0
>             bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
>             logical name: wlp4s0
>             version: 00
>             serial: 64:6e:69:8b:31:03
>             width: 64 bits
>             clock: 33MHz
>             capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
>             configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.4.0-37-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.90 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
>             resources: irq:150 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7300000-f730ffff
> ```

```
$lspci -nnx
```

> 04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE

> 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]

> 00: ec 10 22 b8 07 04 10 00 00 00 80 02 10 00 00 00

> 10: 01 d0 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 30 f7 00 00 00 00

> 20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 43 10 46 87

> 30: 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 01 00 00

```
systemctl status bluetooth
```

> ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: inactive (dead)
> Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

> Jun 18 08:53:17 kiwi systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.